# How to prevent a function from running on mouse click until previous completes

Tags: python, multithreading, mouselistener, pynput

I'm trying to setup a mouse listener in Python which runs a function on mouse click, as long as that function isn't already running.

```html
from pynput import mouse

def do_work(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(f"Button pressed. Doing work.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f"Finished work.")

# Setup mouse listener.
with mouse.Listener(on_click=do_work) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

So in the above example, even if I smash the mouse button continuously, `do_work` will only ever run every three seconds.

It feels like I should be able to set this up in a thread but I don't know how to pass the thread into `do_work` such that it can test if the thread is alive.

Comment: use some variable to control it `is_running = True/False`

Comment: I test `is_running` but I found different problem - when it uses `sleep` then it blocks `do_work` and it doesn't get other clicks and it can't skip them - clicks wait in queue until `sleep` finish job and `do_work` execute anoter `sleep` for every click which was in the past. `do_work` would have to create thread and assing to global variable - and later it can use this varaible to check if thread is still running (or if varaible is `None`). You don't have to pass thread into `do_work`, you have to create thread inside `do_work`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_work` runs `sleep` which blocks `listener` for longer time and `listener` can't get other clicks from system, and it can't skip them - they wait until `sleep` finish job and then `listener` gets these clicks from past and runs `do_work` again and again.

You would have to run `do_work` in theard. `Listener` shouldn't runs directly `do_work` but it should run other function (ie. `on_click`) and this function should check clicks and start `do_work` in separated thread or skip clicks.

```
from pynput import mouse
import time
import threading

# --- functions ---

def do_work(x, y, button, pressed):
    print("Button pressed. Doing work.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Finished work.")

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global job
    
    if pressed:
        if job is None or not job.is_alive():
            job = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(x, y, button, pressed))
            job.start()
        #else:
        #    print("skiping this click")
    
# --- main ---

job = None  # default value at start

# Setup mouse listener.
with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    # ... other code ...
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I wrote something similar (which didn't work) and didn't realise I could do that with a global. Thanks!